# Change status bar color when orientation changes

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So, I want to change systemNavigationBarColor and statusBarColor dynamically. Here's my attempt:

```
void systemColors(Orientation orientation) {
print('orientation changed -> $orientation');
if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.blue,
    statusBarColor: Colors.green,
   ),
 );
} else {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.green,
        statusBarColor: Colors.blue),
  );
}
```

Now, this function is called every time the orientation changes, before a return statement returning a Scaffold, inside a build function of a StatelessWidget; I've tried a StatefulWidget with the same results.

The logs confirm it. The orientation that is passed to the function is also the correct one.

However, the UI only updates once, the first time the function is called, either in portrait or landscape orientation, and the UI is update with the specified colors for each scenario.

When the orientation changes, although the function is called, the UI does not update.

Any ideas why?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to do it, not using the System Chrome, but actually by wrapping a Widget with an Annotated Region Widget, like this:

```
Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

// return widget
return AnnotatedRegion(
  value: orientation == Orientation.portrait
         ? widget.appThemeData.systemColorsPortrait(orientation)
         : widget.appThemeData.systemColorsLandscape(orientation),
  child: Scaffold( // code continues on..
```

The systemColorPortrait function looks like this:

```
SystemUiOverlayStyle systemColorsPortrait(Orientation orientation) {
  // log
  print('systemColorsPortrait called with orientation = $orientation');

  // logic
  return SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: _constants.kDarkColor,
    statusBarColor: _constants.kTransparentColor);
}
```

This was done inside a Stateful Widget;
AppThemeData is a class where I stored information about theming, and Constants is a class where I stored constants used throughout the app.